# don't get response from the server ajax

Tags: ajax, response

I don't get a response from the server when I post data to it using ajax.. My code given below..

```
<body>
```

$(document).ready(function()
{
    var contentType ="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";

```
if(window.XDomainRequest)
    contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8;";

$("#postdata").click(function()
{
    $.ajax({
     crossDomain: true,
     url:"http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
     type:"POST",
    data:"api_key=985nn5765n54333ggf666&api_secret=:hjk435jkk345j34hjjjkcjkkjn46665ny&username=colin123&email=jotcoli23h@gmail.com&password=123",

     dataType:"jsonp",   
     contentType:contentType,    
     success:function(data)
     {
        alert("Data from Server"+JSONP.stringfy(data));
     },
     error:function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown)
     {
        alert("You can not send Cross Domain AJAX requests: "+errorThrown);
     }
    });
```

Comment: Have you set breakpoints in your browser's debugger? What does your webserver's error log say? (if you have access to it?)

Comment: i get this error as alert.   You can not send Cross Domain AJAX requests: Error: jQuery191043080363332274096_1413644480462 was not called

Comment: in the browser console response is like that..   status:"500" internal server error..

Comment: The likely cause is that your server-side script failed. Since it sent back an http error message your jQuery error handler is getting called. You will probably be able to diagnose the problem if you have access to the webserver error logs.